# supertest changing url at every test

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs, supertest

I'm new to backend development and i face a problem that i don't understand.

I set up the 1st route of my API called "health" who just return a simple message to know if my server is up.

This route looks to works as expected.

However,

when I try to test this route with the method "toMatchSnapshot" from 
jest API, the test is not passing because of the in the url is changing constantly.

My test file "index.test.ts":

```
const request = supertest.agent(app);
describe("app", () => {

  it("should return a successful response for GET /health", async () => {
    const res = await request.get("/health");
    res.header = omit(res.header, ["date"]);
    expect(res).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

});
```

index of the server "index.ts":

```
const app = express();

expressService(app);

if (require.main === module) {
  app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log("server started at http://localhost:" + PORT);
  });
}

export default app;
```

my function "expressService":

```
const expressService = (app: Application) => {
    app.use(cors());
    app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
    app.use(express.json());

    app.use(api);
};

export default expressService;
```

My PORT variable: `PORT = 3000;`

```
-     "url": "http://127.0.0.1:49694/health",
+     "url": "http://127.0.0.1:52568/health",
```

this is where the test is failing.

Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The doc of `supertest` says:

> You may pass an http.Server, or a Function to request() - if the server is not already listening for connections then it is bound to an ephemeral port for you so there is no need to keep track of ports.

You need to pass a Node.js `http.Server` object to `supertest.agent()`, then you can use the specific `PORT` for testing.

Here is the solution:

`index.ts`:

```js
import express from 'express';
import expressService from './expressService';
import http from 'http';

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

expressService(app);

function createHttpServer() {
  const httpServer: http.Server = app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log('server started at http://localhost:' + PORT);
  });

  return httpServer;
}

if (require.main === module) {
  createHttpServer();
}

export default createHttpServer;
```

`expressService.ts`:

```js
import { Application } from 'express-serve-static-core';
import express, { Router } from 'express';
import cors from 'cors';

const expressService = (app: Application) => {
  app.use(cors());
  app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
  app.use(express.json());

  const api = Router();

  api.get('/health', (req, res) => {
    res.sendStatus(200);
  });

  app.use(api);
};

export default expressService;
```

`index.spec.ts`:

```js
import createHttpServer from './';
import { agent } from 'supertest';
import { omit } from 'lodash';

const httpServer = createHttpServer();
const request = agent(httpServer);

afterAll(done => {
  httpServer.close(done);
});

describe('app', () => {
  it('should return a successful response for GET /health', async () => {
    const res = await request.get('/health');
    res.header = omit(res.header, ['date']);
    expect(res).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

Unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/57409561/index.spec.ts (7.853s)
  app
    ✓ should return a successful response for GET /health (61ms)

  console.log src/stackoverflow/57409561/index.ts:12
    server started at http://localhost:3000

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   1 passed, 1 total
Time:        8.66s
```

Snapshot:

```
// Jest Snapshot v1

exports[`app should return a successful response for GET /health 1`] = `
Object {
  "header": Object {
    "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
    "connection": "close",
    "content-length": "2",
    "content-type": "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
    "etag": "W/\\"2-nOO9QiTIwXgNtWtBJezz8kv3SLc\\"",
    "x-powered-by": "Express",
  },
  "req": Object {
    "data": undefined,
    "headers": Object {
      "user-agent": "node-superagent/3.8.3",
    },
    "method": "GET",
    "url": "http://127.0.0.1:3000/health",
  },
  "status": 200,
  "text": "OK",
}
`;
```

Here is the completed demo: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/57409561

Comment: upvoted! how do you put the request variable inside the global setup and global teardown file in jest and access it from within a test everywhere else

Comment: This solution works!

Answer (score 0):

Simple enough solution:

```js
const request = require('supertest'); // npm i -ED supertest
const app = require('../app'); // your expressjs app
const { url } = request(app).get('/'); // next, just use url
console.debug(url); // prints: http://127.0.0.1:57516/
```