# Jest + Supertest - API tests are using random ephemeral ports

Tags: node.js, jestjs, supertest, restify

I'm using Restify for my API and I'm trying to write tests for my endpoints.
At first, I had only a test for `ping` and it was okay, but now, after I added a new test, `supertest` is trying to ephemeral ports to the test server (80201).

I've searched a lot and tried some approaches that seem to work for most people but not for me. I'm probably messing something up, but I have no clue what it could be.

Check out my code:

**server.js**

```js
require('dotenv').config();

const config = require('./config');
const routes = require('./src/routes');

const cors = require('restify-cors-middleware');
const http = require('http');
const https = require('https');
const restify = require('restify');


module.exports = function () {
    http.globalAgent.keepAlive = true;
    http.globalAgent.maxSockets = 256;
    https.globalAgent.keepAlive = true;
    https.globalAgent.maxSockets = 256;

    const _cors = cors({
        preflightMaxAge: 5,
        origins: [new RegExp("^(https?:\/\/)?[-\w]+\.hackz\.co(\.\w+)?(:[\d]+)?$")],
        allowHeaders: [
            'authorization',
            'x-requested-with',
            'Content-MD5',
            'Date',
            'Accept-Version',
            'Api-Version',
            'Response-Time'
        ],
        credentials: true
    });

    const server = restify.createServer({ name: config.apiName });

    // Middlewares
    server.pre(_cors.preflight);
    server.use(_cors.actual);
    server.use(restify.plugins.fullResponse());
    server.use(restify.plugins.queryParser({ mapParams: true }));
    server.use(restify.plugins.bodyParser({ mapParams: true }));

    // Load Routes
    routes.set(server);

    server.on('error', function (req, res, route, error) {
        if (error && (error.statusCode == null || error.statusCode !== 404)) {}
    });

    // Start Server
    server.listen(config.apiPort, function () {
        console.log(`${server.name} listening at ${server.url}.\nWe're in ${config.env} environment!`);
    });

    return server;
}();
```

**tests/config/server.js**

```js
const server = require('../..');
const request = require('supertest');

function TestServer() {
    return request(server);
}

module.exports = { TestServer };
```

**tests/services/request.js**

```js
const { TestServer } = require("../config/server");


async function get(path, sessionkey = '', params = {}) {
    const server = TestServer();
    return await server
        .get(path)
        .query(params)
        .set("authorization", sessionkey)
        .set("content-type", "application/json")
    ;
}

async function post(path) {
    const server = TestServer();
    return await server
        .post(path)
        .set("content-type", "application/json")
    ;
}

module.exports = {
    get,
    post,
};
```

**tests/config/setup.js**

```js
const server = require('../..');


afterAll(() => {
    return server.close()
});
```

**src/controllers/Ping.test.js**

```js
const { get } = require('../../tests/services/request');


describe('Ping Controller', () => {
    describe('GET /ping', () => {
        it('Should return 200', async () => {
            const response = await get('/ping');
            expect(response.status).toBe(200);
        });
    });
});
```

**src/controllers/Session.test.js**

```js
const { post } = require('../../tests/services/request');


describe('Session Controller', () => {
    const userId = 1;
    describe('POST /:userId/create', () => {
        it('Should create session successfully!', async () => {
            const response = await post(`${userId}/create`);
            expect(response.status).toBe(200);
            expect(response.body.auth).toBe(true);
        });
    });
});
```

**package.json (scripts and Jest config)**

```json
...

"scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "test": "jest --detectOpenHandles --forceExit --coverage",
    "test:api": "npm run test -- --roots ./src/controllers"
},

...

"jest": {
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "jest-extended",
      "<rootDir>/tests/config/setup.js"
    ],
    ...
}
```

This is the error output:

```sh
> user-session-api@1.0.0 test
> jest --detectOpenHandles --forceExit --coverage

 FAIL  src/controllers/Session.test.js
  Session Controller
    POST /:userId/create
      ✕ Should create session successfully! (39 ms)

  ● Session Controller › POST /:userId/create › Should create session successfully!

    RangeError: Port should be >= 0 and < 65536. Received 80201.RangeError [ERR_SOCKET_BAD_PORT]: Port should be >= 0 and < 65536. Received 80201.
```

Things I've tried:

- Passing the result of `server.listen(...)` (instead of the server instance) to `supertest` (as described [here](https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest/issues/489#issuecomment-404973029));
- Using `beforeEach` for each test manually listening to a specific port;
- [This approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57409561/supertest-changing-url-at-every-test), which is similar to the first item.

HELP!

**UPDATE**:
Just realized that running `npm run test "Ping.test.js"` it succeeds and running `npm run test "Session.test.js"` (which is the new test) it fails. So there's probably something wrong with that single file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OH MY GOD!

I found the issue and, prepare yourself, the solution is ridiculous.

The request path in my test had a typo.

I was doing this:

```js
const response = await post(`${userId}/create`); // with userId as 1
```

The path was missing an initial `/`, that's it haha.

THAT'S why `supertest` was appending a `1` to the server port and the `RangeError` was raised.

I'm hating myself right now.

Answer (score 2):

I was also getting this error:

> RangeError [ERR_SOCKET_BAD_PORT]: Port should be >= 0 and < 65536. Received 80201

Using supertest and Jest to test a NestJS application. I was also doing a

```
return request(app.getHttpServer())
  .get(`route`)
```

Instead of

```
return request(app.getHttpServer())
  .get(`/route`)
```